# Failed to verify contract source code due to timeout/memory limit

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, ropsten, verify, contract-verification

Failed to verify contract deployed through remix on Ropsten network both using optimization and without it.

Error is:

`Exception #1 Occured: ERROR|The Contract solidity compilation has exceeded the maximum timeout/memory limit that we can safely process. Automated source code verification is unavailable for this source code.`

Gas estimation of creating contract with optimization:

`gas  2592372 gas
 transaction cost   2592372 gas`

Without optimization:

`gas     4570491 gas
 transaction cost   4570491 gas`

Tried both of Verify Contract Code (version 2.0) and Standart Version.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using one rather large file to do the verification and have the full source code in there.

What you can to do overcome this issue, is strip out the code in all classes your contract is calling and just use them as interfaces.

Just keep actual code that said address is using and make sure you don't have any ABI loops.

Have a look at this [Validated Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x29632c10d76bd1aed6b1524bf5bde4c992610670#code)